# Is it possible to join directly い-adj + この + noun?

Tags: syntax, phrases, parsing

I came across this multiple choice sentence within my homework exercises:
[image]

I assume that the correct answer is 気に入った. However, the この demonstrative seems out of place to me. I would rather use just one modifier, either 自然が多い or この like this:

> 自然が多い町が気に入った。
>   この町が気に入った。

or, using both 自然か多い and この, I would say something like:

> 自然が多**くて**、この町が気に入った。

However, I can't understand why and how come both modifiers are put together directly in this fashion:

> **自然が多いこの**町…

What am I missing here?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't understand why and how come both modifiers are put together directly in this fashion: 自然が多いこの町...

In the phrase 「自然が多いこの町」, 自然が多い is a relative clause that modifies この町.

［自然が多い］この町
This town ［which has a lot of nature /which is rich in nature］
< Its non-relative version is:
この町は、自然が多い。 This town is rich in nature.

> Is it possible to join directly い-adj + この + noun?

Yes. You can say 「自然が多**い**この町」, 「美し**い**その町」, 「かわい**い**あの子」 etc. but NOT 「自然が多く**て**この町」, 「美しく**て**その町」, 「かわいく**て**あの子」 etc.

When combining an adjective and a demonstrative determiner, you use the attributive form (連体形) of the adjective, like this...

かわいい子 + あの子 (i-adjective + demonstrative determiner)
→ ◎「かわい**い**あの子」 but not ☓「かわいく**て**あの子」

きれいな家 + この家 (na-adjective + demonstrative determiner)
→ ◎「きれい**な**この家」 but not ☓「きれい**で**この家」

Compare:

自然が多い町 + きれいな町 (i-adjective + na-adjective)
→ ◎「自然が多く**て**きれいな町」 〇「自然が多**い**きれいな町」

きれいな町 + 静かな町 (na-adjective + na-adjective)
→ ◎「きれい**で**静かな街」 〇～△「きれいな静かな街」

優しい人 + かわいい人 (i-adjective + i-adjective)
→ ◎「優しく**て**かわいい人」 〇～△「優しいかわいい人」

Comment: If I understood correctly, you mean that 「自然が多いこの町」 would be equivalent to 「この自然が多い町」? . So far, I thought of 「この自然が多い町」 as "from those cities that have plenty of nature, this one". I.E., the この applies to the whole 「自然が多い町」. I mean, from the group of "cities with plenty of nature", we pick "this" particular one by using the article この.

Comment: However, this idea of concreting one instance of city from a group can not be applied to 「自然が多いこの町」, as "from this city, the one taht has plenty of nature" does not make sense at all (because in this case there is no generic group, but the "plenty of nature" modifier acts directly on "this" single city). So, do both just mean "this city with plenty of nature", regardless of the order of the modifiers?

Comment: Posted the last new question as a new Stack question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68361/32952)

Answer (score 1):

この文章は、次のように置き換えて考えると分かりやすいかもしれません。

> この町は自然が多いので、（私は）この町が気に入りました。

これを短くまとめると、「自然が多いこの町が気に入った」になります。

これを

> 自然が多い町が気に入った。 （その中でも）この町が気に入った。

のように2つの文に分けてしまうと、最初の文に「自然が多い場所なら、どの町でもいい」という意味が足されてしまいます。問題文では「この町」を気に入ったと限定しているので、「自然が多い町が気に入った。 この町が気に入った。」とは言い換えられない事になります。

> 自然が多くて、この町が気に入った。

という表現は（「多くて」の部分が若干不自然に感じますが）可能です。

---

求められている解答は「気に入った」だと思いますが、実は「気になった」でも日本語の文章としては正解です。（意味は変わってしまいます。また、前後の文脈も見ながら、どちらが適切か判断する必要があります。）

「自然が多いこの町が気になった」の場合は、「この町は自然が多いので、（私は）この町が気になりました」を省略した形ととらえるのが良いかと思います。